# Yii criteria params array whit strstr function

Tags: php, yii, criteria, strstr, cactivedataprovider

I have this criteria params array (i try this, but it's not working):

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('mydata', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition' => 'row=:id', 
                'params' => array(**strstr(':id', '.')** => '.com') 
        ),
```

i need to add a `strstr` function to a `params` how can i do that?

thanx from advance

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want to compare the word after first dot (.com) to = '.com'

Answer (score 1):

You should call the strstr function at the right place first of all:

```
'params' => array(':id' => strstr('.com', '.'))
```

Also make sure you actually want [strstr](http://www.php.net/strstr) as:

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.

Comment: i am sure that i want to use "strstr" but i want to compare ":id" to google.com, so i want to read the ":id" (lets say: google.ru) after do. so it will be like .ru => .com

Comment: Criteria / Params doesn't work like that. Params contains an `array(key => value)` where key represents the condition placeholder in `condition`. You need to modify the condition to reflect what you actually want to compare: `'condition' => "'.com'=:id",`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to do but parameters should be used directly as values for queries.

You can parse/work with the parameter before sending it to the criteria or you could also try changing your query to work as you need it to. If you can provide me a more detailed example, maybe I can give you another opinion.